# How call function which is return from another one?

Tags: function, scala, call, spray

I am trying to call function to marshal [HttpResponse](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/api/index.html#spray.http.HttpResponse) from [spray](http://spray.io/). `unmarshal` function described [here](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/ResponseTransformation.scala). response is [HttpResponse](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/api/index.html#spray.http.HttpResponse)

Consider 3 code variants:

## First

```
val func = unmarshal[MyType]
func(response)
```

## Second

```
unmarshal[MyType].apply(response)
```

## Third

```
unmarshal[MyType](response)
```

Why does my third code variant does not compile while first two are works? The compiler returns:

```
[error]  found   : spray.http.HttpResponse
[error]  required: spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromResponseUnmarshaller[MyType]
[error]     (which expands to)  spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Deserializer[spray.http.HttpResponse,MyType]
[error]         unmarshal[MyType](response)
```

Is there a way to call function returned by `unmarshal` more elegant then create temp variable or direct call `apply` method?

Comment: The second and third are identical.  Did you paste the wrong thing by mistake?

Comment: I have not written a single scala-line (yet) but I would guess at least `(unmarshal[MyType])(response)` should work in a reasonable (FP) language

Comment: Sorry about wrong third example. Question updated.

Comment: 2Carsten, you are generally right and I have tried this already, but compiler complains with same error. :(

Comment: well sorry ... I can already tell I like scala ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of that function is (from your link):

```
  def unmarshal[T: FromResponseUnmarshaller]
```

so the `T` needs implicit evidence that there's such a `FromResponseUnmarshaller` for it. The signature actually compiles to something like:

```
 def unmarshal[T](implicit evidence$1: FromResponseUnmarshaller[T]): HttpResponse ⇒ T
```

That means, the `unmarshal` function actually takes also an implicit parameter that should transform your `MyType` to an `HttpResponse`.

In your first example, you call `val func = unmarshal[MyType]` which makes the compiler insert the implicit for you. In your 3rd example,

```
 unmarshal[MyType](response)
```

`response` is taking the position of the implicit parameter, which is supposed to be a `FromResponseUnmarshaller`, not a `HttpResponse`.

Such a call would need to be:

```
unmarshal[MyType](fromResponseUnmarshsaller)(response)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
       This is the original method call          Here you apply response to the returned function.
```

Comment: I do not see any of implicit parameters in line `def unmarshal[T: FromResponseUnmarshaller]: HttpResponse ⇒ T` from `unmarshal` function source. Could please add more details about implicit parameters for `unmarshal` function?

Comment: @Cherry, the parameter is included there by defining `[T : FromResponseUnmarshaller]`. Try creating a function on the REPL, like `def f [T: List] = 0`, you'll see that the REPL defines it as `f: [T](implicit evidence$1: List[T])Int`. For more info, check @dcastro's link

Comment: Thanks. It seems there is no way to skip implicit context bound parameters from call statement. :(